# Deserializing JSON containing an array of headers and a separate nested array of rows

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I want to read from a page using an API which is giving me the results in the nested JSON format below:

```
{
    "rootEntity": "function",
    "count": 92516,
    "header": ["eventNumber", "startDate", "eventType"],
    "results": [
        ["40262-1", "Tuesday, December 12, 2017", "Corporate"],
        ["14361-1", "Monday, October 23, 2017", "School"],
        ["5014-1", "Friday, October 13, 2017", "Birthday"]
    ]
}
```

Below is the code I am using to deserialize the JSON. But it is throwing an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{         
     JObject o = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(new JsonTextReader(reader));

     reader.Close();
     JArray jarr = (JArray)o["results"];

     jsonString = String.Join("\\", jarr);
}

jsonString = jsonString.Trim('"');

var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebResp>(jsonString);
jsonResponse = resp.results.ToArray();
```

Comment: *... in different Json format which is quite different ...* - What? It is a valid JSON. What is quite different from different (whatever that means)?

Comment: Hi Rufu..Of course.. It is valid json. Its just that I encountered it for the first time.

Comment: "But it is throwing me error" => what is the error ?

Comment: post your `WebResp` class. Also, why are you doing all of this json string stuff before you deserialize?  What line is throwing the error?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  In order to help you, we need to see a [mcve] that reproduces your problem, which would include the JSON you are deserializing and the c# types (here `WebResp`) you are trying to deserialize to.  You've shared your JSON and your deserialization code so you're more than halfway there, can you share `WebResp` also?  See also [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for tips how to write a question that is more likely to get answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a helper method like the following to convert the results from the response stream into a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`:

```
static List<Dictionary<string, string>> GetResultsFromResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    using (JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(jsonReader);
        JArray keys = (JArray)obj["header"];
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> results = obj["results"]
            .Children<JArray>()
            .Select(a => keys.Zip(a, (k, v) => new { Key = (string)k, Value = (string)v })
                             .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value))
            .ToList();

        return results;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this, for example:

```
var results = GetResultsFromResponseStream(responseStream);

foreach (var item in results)
{
    foreach (var kvp in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

```
eventNumber: 40262-1
startDate: Tuesday, December 12, 2017
eventType: Corporate

eventNumber: 14361-1
startDate: Monday, October 23, 2017
eventType: School

eventNumber: 5014-1
startDate: Friday, October 13, 2017
eventType: Birthday
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UdFBtD