# Map JSON string array of headers and nested array of results to C# Generic

Tags: c#, json, list, json.net

I am working with a service that returns the following JSON. While I can use Newtonsoft to deserialize into a C# Generic, the string array of headers, then nested array of results has thrown me a curveball. Instead of mapping to a string array, I would really like to have a List that are strongly typed and mapped.

```
{
    "rootEntity": "function",
    "count": 2,
    "header": [
        "name",
        "email",
        "function"
    ],
    "results": [
        [
            "12 HOURS",
            "test@test.com",
            "testing"
        ],
        [
            "Example",
            "example@test.com",
            "second"
        ]
    ]
}
```

The service does allow you to add more fields, which is why it includes both the headers and then results, but those results will not be strongly typed.

My goal is to have a model that looks like:

```
public class EventResults
{
    public string? RootEntity { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public List<Events> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Events
{
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Function { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to better convert this to a C# Object without hoping that same `name` is always in string[0]?

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [Deserializing JSON containing an array of headers and a separate nested array of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48148903).

Comment: `results` is an array of an array of strings; there is not a "type" with properties to bind to. What "type" would you prefer to bind `results` to?

Comment: How does your C# class look that you want to deserialize to?

Comment: @DStanley - Basically the sender "compressed" the JSON by ensuring the property names of the "results" objects appear only once by using the "header" array of strings for result property names and an array of array of values for result property values.  The "header" strings correspond to the property names of each "result" item.  OP would like to deserialize those header + result arrays to a single `List<TItem>`.  [Deserializing JSON containing an array of headers and a separate nested array of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48148903/3744182) is a previous example.

Comment: @DStanley they are all arrays of strings, even non-string values. The type is more to a generic class, even if all strings, that is at least strongly typed AND mapped to the headers.

Comment: @Magnus very standard, honestly to even start a generic of say Event, and 3 strings of name, email, function.

Comment: @dbc I need to better read/understand that - but even the structure of my JSON looks the same. But also wasn't really expecting a List<Dictionary<string, string>> as much as a class (eventually like List<event>).

Comment: @jmlumpkin - fair enough.  Then might you please [edit] your question to share your desired C# data model, starting from your root object?  That would clarify your requirements.  (E.g. do `rootEntity` and `count` also need to be bound?)

Answer (score 1):

You have some data model like this:

```
public class EventResults
{
    public string? RootEntity { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public List<Events> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Events
{
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Function { get; set; }
}
```

And you would like to deserialize JSON to this model that has been "compressed" by converting the `Events` array of objects to an array of array of property values named `"results"`, and moving the property names of each event object to a separate array of strings called `"headers"`.

You can do this with a generic converter such as the following:

```
public class ObjectWithResultArrayConverter<TModel> : JsonConverter<TModel> where TModel : class, new()
{
    protected virtual string HeadersName => "header";
    protected virtual string ResultsName => "results";
    
    public override TModel? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, TModel? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!(serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType) is JsonObjectContract contract))
            throw new NotImplementedException("Contract is not a JsonObjectContract");
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Transform "results" from an array of array of values to an array of objects:
        var headers = jObj.GetValue(HeadersName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase).RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent() as JArray;
        var resultsProperty = jObj.Property(ResultsName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase).RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent();
        if (headers != null && resultsProperty?.Value is JArray results)
        {
            var resultsJArray = new JArray(results.Children<JArray>().Select(innerArray => new JObject(headers.Zip(innerArray, (h, i) => new JProperty((string)h!, i)))));
            jObj[resultsProperty.Name] = resultsJArray;
        }
        
        // Construct the TModel and populate it with the transformed JSON values.
        var value = existingValue ?? (TModel?)contract.DefaultCreator?.Invoke() ?? new TModel();
        serializer.Populate(jObj.CreateReader(), value);
        return value;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, TModel? value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(reader);
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(reader);
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }

    public static TJToken? RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent<TJToken>(this TJToken? node) where TJToken : JToken
    {
        if (node == null)
            return null;
        JToken toRemove;
        var property = node.Parent as JProperty;
        if (property != null)
        {
            // Also detach the node from its immediate containing property -- Remove() does not do this even though it seems like it should
            toRemove = property;
            property.Value = null!;
        }
        else
        {
            toRemove = node;
        }
        if (toRemove.Parent != null)
            toRemove.Remove();
        return node;
    }
}
```

Then add [`[JsonProperty("results")]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) to the `Events` property:

```
[JsonProperty("results")] // ADD THIS
public List<Events> Events { get; set; }
```

Finally deserialize by adding the converter to `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters` e.g. as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new ObjectWithResultArrayConverter<EventResults>() },
    // Add other settings as required, e.g.
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
};
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventResults>(jsonString, settings);
```

Notes:

- The converter assumes that the object has a `Results` property.  This assumption can be changed by overriding `ResultsName`.
- Serialization in the same format is not implemented.  Your model will be re-serialized using default serialization as follows:

  ```json
  {
    "rootEntity": "function",
    "count": 2,
    "results": [
      {
        "name": "12 HOURS",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "function": "testing"
      },
      {
        "name": "Example",
        "email": "example@test.com",
        "function": "second"
      }
    ]
  }
  ```
- The question *[Deserializing JSON containing an array of headers and a separate nested array of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48148903)* deals with a similar situation where the `"results"` array is to be mapped to a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cDOWDP).